# GradientTape returns None when run through custom training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using `tf.GradientTape` in a custom training loop to train a model on some timeseries data from a telescope. I am using keras optimizer and loss functions: `keras.optimizers.Adam` and `keras.losses.MeanSquaredError`. I have two training loops, one works, and the second one `train_sequential` does not as `tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)` returns None for the gradient.

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

loss_function = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

def train_traditional(model:keras.models.Sequential,
                      training_data:pd.DataFrame,
                      validation_data:pd.DataFrame,
                      sequence_length:int,
                      headers,
                      epochs=1):
    # Combine data
    data = pd.concat([training_data, validation_data])
    # Extract features and targets
    features = data[headers].values
    targets = data[headers].shift(-sequence_length).values
    # Remove incomplete sequences
    num_sequences = len(features) - sequence_length
    features = features[:num_sequences]
    targets = targets[:num_sequences]
    # Training loop
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Shuffle data
        indices = np.random.permutation(num_sequences)
        features_shuffled = features[indices]
        targets_shuffled = targets[indices]
        # Mini-batch training
        losses = []
        for i in range(0, num_sequences, sequence_length):
            batch_features = features_shuffled[i:i+sequence_length]
            batch_targets = targets_shuffled[i:i+sequence_length]
            # Forward pass
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                model_input = np.expand_dims(batch_features, axis=0)
                predictions = model(model_input)
                loss = loss_function(batch_targets, predictions)
                losses.append(loss.numpy())
            # Backpropagation
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}: Steps {num_sequences}: Loss = {np.average(losses)}')
        losses.clear()
    print('Training finished.')

def train_sequential(model:keras.models.Sequential,
                     training_data:pd.DataFrame,
                     validation_data:pd.DataFrame,
                     epochs=10):
    tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()
    # Training loop
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Forward pass
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predicted_sequence = generate_predicted_sequence(model, training_data)
            loss = loss_function(validation_data, predicted_sequence)
            val = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
            for v in val:
                print(v)
            print(f"Loss: {loss}")
        # Backpropagation
        gradients = val
        for layer in model.layers:
            print(layer.trainable_variables)
        print(f'gradients: {gradients}')
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}: Loss: {loss.numpy()}')
    print('Training finished.')

def generate_predicted_sequence(model, input_data):
    predicted_sequence = input_data
    for i in range(len(predicted_sequence)):
        model_input = predicted_sequence
        model_input = np.reshape(model_input, (1, 15, 4))
        result = model(model_input)
        predicted_sequence = np.vstack((predicted_sequence[1:], result))
    return predicted_sequence
```

Both `training_data` and `validation_data` are pandas DataFrames with the same number of rows and datetime index. I am certain that somewhere in my sequence generation I am messing something up for the GradientTape since the same data works fine when run through the traditional training loop. The following is the model I am using:

```
Input Shape: (None, 15, 4)
Model: "SimpleLSTM15"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                       ┃ Output Shape                  ┃     Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ lstm (LSTM)                        │ (None, 64)                    │      17,664 │
├────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ dense_8 (Dense)                    │ (None, 4)                     │         260 │
└────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
 Total params: 17,924 (70.02 KB)
 Trainable params: 17,924 (70.02 KB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
```

Comment: Do not use numpy functions inside the `GradientTape`! To get gradients w.r.t to the input, every operation has to be a TensorFlow function/method as they capture gradients, and numpy does not (why should it?). I suspect `np.vstack(..)` inside `generate_predicted_sequence`. Change it to the appropiate tf version. In general, there is almost always an equal tf version for a numpy function.

Comment: To be even more general, to maximize the efficiency of your training loop, try to use only tf functions, especially on gpu. Transforming a tensor back to a numpy array, and therefore sending it back to cpu, is expensive and slow.

Comment: Thank you, searching the docs for the tf equivalents. I was incredibly confused when I got back a loss but couldn't backpropagate.